# reload a module in python for debugging purposes

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning python and to test and debug the class I am creating I need to be able to reload it in the live python interface. My file is OderedDictionary.py 
I import it doing
`import OderedDictionary`
I read that to reload it I shoud do `OderedDictionary.reload()` since I am using python3.7, but I get a:

`AttributeError: module 'OrderedDictionary' has no attribute 'reload'`

I also tried to use `reload(module)` directly, but I got this:

```
NameError: name 'reoad' is not defined
```

Maybe I misunderstood something?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unload (reload) a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-module)

Comment: No I tried, I have this: NameError: name 'reload' is not defined

Comment: You should get an ImportError then. Did you do `from importlib import reload`?

Comment: that was it! I didn't know I needed a library for the reload, thank you

Comment: It say right at the start of the answer of the duplicate, at the top of the code sample.